# javascript filter method doesnt return one result

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a filter's method on array, where I have a symbols of regions. Then I would like to equal to my results from HTTP request. When result is true it should `console.log("profile")`, when false, should return `console.log("rejected")`. But regardless of the result, there is always `console.log("profile")`

```
 .getProfile(id, token)
    .then(data => {
      let data = data.data;
      let regions = ["SP", "RS", "PR", "MG", "SC"];
   if (
        regions.filter(reg => {
          console.log(reg);
          console.log(data.region === reg);
          return reg === data.region; // it is false, because data.region is AC
        })
      ) {
        console.log("profile");
      } else console.log("rejected");
    })
```

So in console my result are: 
[image]

So.. I am wondering, why, when `reg === data.region` is false, I have `console.log("profile)`. It should be rejected. Any hint where the error lies?

Comment: You need to check the length of the array for the return results of filter. [] is not falsey. 0 is.

Comment: [Falsy values in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let regions = ["SP", "RS", "PR", "MG", "SC"];

let result = regions.filter(a => a === 'AC');
```

It give you to blank array which is not a `falsy` value

so thats why if condition run...

> You can use The some() method tests whether at least one element in
>   the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It
>   returns a Boolean value.

```
  let regions = ["SP", "RS", "PR", "MG", "SC"];

let result = regions.some(a => a === 'AC');
// or you can use `includes`
let result1 = regions.includes('AC'); 

now result contain a boolean value
```

You can do like this i refactor your code

```
.getProfile(id, token)
    .then(data => {
      let data = data.data;
      let regions = ["SP", "RS", "PR", "MG", "SC"];
      let result = regions.some(reg =>  reg === data.region);  // it is false, because data.region is AC
    if (result) {
        console.log("profile");
      } else  {

      }console.log("rejected");
    })
```

Comment: hehe you've been faster than me :)

Comment: @Cid  sometimes :P

Answer (score 1):

`filter` method returns array, and if no matches, it returns an empty array. Even if array is empty it interpreted as `true`

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to an empty array evaluating truthy

```js
if([])
  console.log("Empty arrays are truthy");
```

Fix it by checking the length

```js
if([].length)
   console.log("You wont see this.")
```

`0` is falsey!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `includes` method:

```
if (regions.includes('AC')) {

}
```

or you can check length of filtered array:

```
let length = regions.filter(reg => {
          console.log(reg);
          console.log(data.region === reg);
          return reg === data.region;
        }).length;

if (length) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, if you don't need to use the filtered array but to log rejected or profile, I'd use `.some()` instead of `.filter()`

```js
const regions = ["SP", "RS", "PR", "MG", "SC"];
const toFind = "foo";

if (regions.some(reg => {
          console.log(reg);
          console.log(toFind === reg);
          return toFind === reg;}))
{
  console.log("profile");
}
else
  console.log("rejected");
```

Answer (score 1):

`filter` will always return an array. In your case, if condition is always truthy because an empty array `[]` is truthy.
Instead of `filter` use `find` this will return `undefined` if nothing matched, which is falsy.

```
.getProfile(id, token)
.then(data => {
  let data = data.data;
  let regions = ["SP", "RS", "PR", "MG", "SC"];
  if (
    regions.find(reg => reg === data.region)
  ) {
    console.log("profile");
  } else console.log("rejected");
})
```